# Amazon EB Having Issues Autoloading My PSR-4 Namespaced Classes

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, psr-4, spl-autoload-register

I wanted to add [PSR-4 namespacing](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for my classes:

```
- app
-- autoloader.php
-- bootstrap.php -> `include 'autoloader.php'`
- public
-- index.php -> `include './../app/bootstrap.php'`
- controllers
-- Test.php
```

controllers/Test.php:

```php
<?php

namespace Controllers;

class Test{}
```

app/autoloader.php (simplified):

```php
<?php
spl_autoload_register('myAutoloader');

function myAutoloader($className) {
    include "./../$classname.php"
}
```

Then at some point I call `Controllers\Test::someMethod()`.

**Locally**, this loads fine. But when I deploy it to my **AWS EB instance**, it fails. So I ran tests to narrow it down to this:

```
var_dump(file_exists('./../controllers/Test.php')); // local: bool(true), AWS: bool(true)
var_dump(file_exists('./../Controllers/Test.php')); // local: bool(true), AWS: bool(false)***
```

On the AWS EB instance, the filename with the capitalized `Controllers` cannot be found, but the lowercased `controllers` can.

How can I configure my EB instance to allow for mixed capitalization?

Answer (score 0):

Did some further digging and found that the issue is the Elastic Beanstalk instance is running on Linux. My local environment is a Mac.

`file_exists()` and `include|require()` are **case-insensitive** on Mac and Windows, but it is **case-sensitive** on a Linux.

So in order to autoload classes without the aid of a library or framework abstraction, I needed to capitalize my directories. Unfortunately, I wouldn't be able to do any of the fancier PSR-4 standards:

```
\Acme\Log\Writer\File_Writer => ./acme-log-writer/lib/File_Writer.php
```

...but I'm sure there are libraries out there that can convert a `$className` to a PSR4 filepath. In the meantime, I'll stick to capitalizing my namespace-directories.